# On complexity of arithmetic operations

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Though there have been many questions asked in this forum on complexity of integer operation, I could not find an answer to the following question: What implications are there to complexity theory if integer addition and multiplication of two integers have the same asymptotic complexity in the worst case?

Comment: In what model of computation? (e.g. circuits, TMs)

Comment: I think for both circuits and TMs superlinear lower bound for multiplication is not known.

Comment: There are models where multiplication can be done in linear time, e.g., pointer machines. A. Schönhage, SIAM J. Comput., 9(3), 490–508.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If integer multiplication is in linear time, then the Hartmanis-Stearns conjecture on real-time computation is false. See [this post](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/why-the-hartmanis-stearns-conjecture-is-still-open/) by Richard Lipton (and Ken Regan?).